# It is possible to Have ObservableCollection of ObservableCollections in viewModel using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I wonder to know if it is possible to have an ObservableCollection of ObservableCollections in viewModel like this:

```
 ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<EditingMetadataViewModel>> MetadatasList = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<EditingMetadataViewModel>>();
```

each ObservableCollection shows a list of metadata when it is binded to the view. In the case I have more than one file selected I want to have the same metadata lists number as selected files number (e.g if I select three files and I want to edit their metadata, I want to have three lists of metadata list).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a ItemsControl(or Panel controls) of ListView, ListBox, Grid, ... as child items:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MetadatasList}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding MetaData}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Where I must to create this ItemsControls

Comment: @naufal_chiadmi, Anywhere in your window or page that accept a control. This answer is walkthrough to accept you can do this, but base on your desire you can using any controls and style.

Comment: @reza_arabqaeni This ItemsControl must be a child of listVIew or not

Comment: @naufal_chiadmi, No ListView is child of ItemsControl.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not and would be very easy for you to verify this. You could quickly create a ListBox that has a data template that contains a ListBox.

For clarity however you may want to define a class `FileMetadata`. In that case the first observable collection will be declared as
    `public ObservableCollection<FileMetadata> FileMetadataList {get; private set; }`

Class `FileMetadata` would contain a member:
    `public ObservableCollection<EditingMetadataViewModel>> MetadatasList {get; private set; }`

This is equivalent with your code but will may make certain parts easier to read and manage.